# CSS Center Image and Text in a column

Tags: html, css, sass

I have the following. As you can see, the image and text are aligned to the left of the column.

**Question**

How do I center the image and text?

I have tried `text-align: center;` on the column, text and image. All having no effect.  Any help appreciated.

[image]

**UPDATE**

I am using Ionic2 to generate the raw html code:

**html**

```
  <ion-row *ngFor="let trio of getTriples()">
    <ion-col *ngFor="let item of trio">
      <div style="text-align:center">
        <div class="row responsive-md">
          {{ formatCategories(item) }}
          <img (click)="toggleCategory(item)" class="item-stable-large filter-image" id="icon-image-{{item.id}}" src="{{item.icon}}"
            [class.item-selected]="itemShown === item" />
          <p class="filter-text">{{item.name}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

**css**

```
.filter-text {
    text-align: center;
}

.filter-image {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Embed your code, don't show screenshots, we can't do much with them.

Comment: Do you know the width of the images? Are they same for all?

Comment: I will update above. However, the problem is my code is written in an Ionic Framework, so the raw html is generated code.

Comment: .responsive-md {display: flex; justify-content: center; flex-direction: column;}

Comment: add css property margin:auto to align it in middle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this,

```
img.filter-image {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

p.filter-text {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 4em;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that centered the it for me. I need to wait 10 min before I can mark this as the solution. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to making the column `position:relative;` and then moving them with:

```
.filter-image {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Move it with `top` and `left` manually.

Answer (score 0):

**Try the following**

It should work, I think.

```
.col {
   align-self: center;
}
```